# Intuit AggCat updateInstitutionLogin 503 DownStreamServiceUnavailable

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

Can someone help me out?  I am not sure if this is an Intuit system error OR an error on my part.  I am able to discoverAndAddAccounts and everything else no problem.  However when I try to updateInstitutionLogin I am getting a 503 DownStreamServiceUnavailable response.

FYI: I get the same response if I leave out refresh=true.

Request:
https://financialdatafeed.platform.intuit.com/v1/logins/136****?refresh=true

```
<InstitutionLogin xmlns="http://schema.intuit.com/platform/fdatafeed/institutionlogin/v1">
        <credentials>
        <credential><name>passcode</name><value>THEPASSWORD</value></credential>
        <credential><name>TAX_AGGR_ENABLED</name><value>FALSE</value></credential>
        <credential><name>onlineID</name><value>THEUSERNAME</value></credential>
        </credentials>
</InstitutionLogin>
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 503 Code:DownStreamServiceUnavailable,Type:SYSTEM
Date: Mon, 23 Dec 2013 12:15:12 GMT
intuit_tid: gw-f4645f18-eac1-4518-b8b4-41756eab406d
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
```

Answer (score 0):

We found the root cause of this issue being that this Login does not have any Accounts under it.  This is causing our system to produce the error that you are seeing.  Please have the user re-discover the account to be able to use the system.